# How to enable bootstrap tooltip and popover (on a bootstrap based theme)?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I'm using a theme based on [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/).

I want to use **Tooltip** and **Popover** features that come with Bootstrap but I couldn't.

It's said on the [Bootstrap Javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) page that:

> Opt-in functionality
>
> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.
>
> One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them
>   by their data-toggle attribute:
>
> ```
> $(function () {
>   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
> })
> ```

I tried to add the code above to my node.tpl.php (inside of  tags) but it didn't work. I also tried to save that code as script.js and added it to my theme info file but it didn't work.

**How can I enable these features? Where to use the above code?**

Comment: The selector needs to select something in the page markup. Do you have any html elements with data-toggle='tooltip' as an attribute?

Comment: @murraybiscuit, yes I have. I tried adding the elements both to node.tpl.php and to block but didn't work:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>`

Comment: Is the code appearing correctly when you inspect the element in the browser?  Also are the any js errors in the console?  It might be that you are just missing one of the dependent scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could enable the tooltip and popover by adding the code below to my `node--mytype.tpl.php`:

```
<script>
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I added this JavaScript to my custom `node--mytype.tpl.php` because I wanted to use tooltip **only** on that content type.

If you want to use the tooltip anywhere on the website (eg on the blocks), you should add the code above to your theme's **`html.tpl.php`** file, just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to enable tooltips/popovers — using `selector` option (see [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4215) and [this](http://jsbin.com/zopod/1/edit?html,css,js,output)):

```
$(document).tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });
$(document).popover({ selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]' });
```

In this way it will work with dynamically generated tooltips/popovers too.

The complete code is:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      $(document).tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });
      $(document).popover({ selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]' });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

You can place it either in:

1. Your theme's `.js` file (don't forget to remove `<script>` tag).
2. `page.tpl.php` template.
3. Custom block (in this case you can easily control on which pages to enable them).

Comment: This is not an answer. You can use any bootstrap based theme and then enable the Tooltip and Popover features. You don't have to use bootstrap base theme.

Comment: It is an answer. It's a pretty bad one, so it may attract downvotes tho'.

Comment: Guys, I just misunderstood the question. Review a new answer now!