# How to show tooltips on form labels based on view filter descriptions in a Bootstrap sub-theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to find a way to display tooltips when a user hovers the mouse over a filter label of a views search page. Preferably, to reduce hard-coding, I would like to take into advantage the filter description and get the tooltip text from there (and subsequently hide descriptions through css).

Also the best way I found to actually activate the tooltips in Bootstrap is to add the attribute `data-toggle="tooltip"` to the element that we need to show a tooltip for.

So far I am using the recipe from [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/50363#comment-50363) adding the `data-toggle` element

```
 function mytheme_form_element($variables){
     dpm($variables);
  $original = theme_form_element($variables);
  $return = '<div data-toggle="tooltip">' . $original . '</div>';   
  return $return;
 }
```

but I don't see the filter description anywhere in the `$variables` array plus this snippet themes the filter field and not the label but would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in form alter, here's an example (add additional conditions yourself):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
  $field_name = 'filter-title';
  $form['title']['#attributes'] = array(
    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
    'data-original-title' => $form['#info'][$field_name]['description']
  );
  $form['#info'][$field_name]['description'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Sounds nice! Is there any way of doing this globally for all views without having to alter all? I'm having a few of them

Comment: Also shall I `unset` the description instead?

Comment: About `unset` - I wouldn't recommend to unset form elements, in some cases it produces warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a good way to do it globally, since views filter field renders in template_preprocess_views_exposed_form() function, you even can't alter it in yours _preprocess_views_exposed_form(), because filter field has already rendered. One dirty way is to replace  template_preprocess_views_exposed_form to yours function, but I would recommend you to use form_alter if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1437850#comment-9232509)

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.

So you have to initialize and use like

```
<script>
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Please visit on [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138424/enable-bootstrap-tooltip-and-popover-on-a-bootstrap-based-theme) post.

Comment: Right, I have already added the snippet above in the `html.tpl.php`. My question is how to show tooltips on filters, where the tooltip text comes from the filter description