# How to show tooltips using a bootstrap sub-theme in a views filter?

Tags: 7, views, bootstrap-theme, tooltips

I am using the bootstrap Tweme theme and would like to **show tooltips when hovering over exposed filters** (e.g. haslanguagecertificate) in a view. When hovering over profile edit fields the help text is shown properly.

I have also added the snippet in html.tpl.php before the closing < / body>.

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
   });
})(jQuery);
```

This has [How to show tooltips on form labels based on view filter descriptions in a Bootstrap sub-theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196880/how-to-show-tooltips-on-form-labels-based-on-view-filter-descriptions-in-a-boots) that helped, but the tooltips are not showing up. Devel does not show ['title']['#attributes'] - what do i have to write here?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
*/

function customisations_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
dpm($form);
// $field_name = 'filter-title';
$field_name = 'filter-field_haslanguagecertificate_value';
$form['title']['#attributes'] = array(
  'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
  'data-original-title' => $form['#info'][$field_name]['description']
  );
 $form['#info'][$field_name]['description'] = '';
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form['title'] needed to be replaced with the fieldname without "filter-".

```
function customisations_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form) {
  //drupal_set_message("setting exposed filter tooltips", 'status');
  //dpm($form);
  $allFilter = array();
  $filtersList = array_keys($form['#info']);

for ($i =0; $i<count($filtersList); $i++) {
    //drupal_set_message("filter " . $filtersList[$i], 'status');
    array_push($allFilter,$filtersList[$i]);
  }

  foreach ($allFilter as $field_name) {
    $fieldTitle = substr($field_name,7); //removes the filter-  
    $form[$fieldTitle]['#attributes'] = array(
    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
    'data-original-title' => $form['#info'][$field_name]['description']
  );
  $form['#info'][$field_name]['description'] = '';
}
}
```